# convert yearly data to monthly in R or vba

Tags: excel, interpolation, type-conversion, vba

someone suggest the L'Aggrange  interpolation, using Vba but i am not an expert in Vba if someone have been use this interpolation before please give any advise. 
i try to make a function in excel vba but it's not  correct

Comment: What does your attempt at programming the function look like?

Answer (score 0):

Doing a brief web search for VBA LAgrange interpolation brought up this file: [LAgrange](http://www.foretrade.com/Downloads/Lagrange.xls)

You could start with that and modify it to fit your needs.